# Align UIImageView with contentMode AspectFill AND Top

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewcontentmode

When I use AspectFill, the image will be centered in image view, top and bottom are cut off. But I want it to start from top, not center. I see many questions but they're all about `AspectFit`, not `AspectFill`. Is there anyway to apply both AspectFill and Top to contentMode of `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found this [UIImageViewAligned](https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned) and decided to answer my own question. It works perfectly.

> It is a subclass of UIImageView that allows you to customize the alignment of the displayed image inside the view's frame. This works even if the contentMode is set to AspectFit, AspectFill or ScaleToFill.